# How to add space between two divs in a Bootstrap column layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to do this style in an archive .html

I want to be able to write inside white text area.

[image]

I'm starting with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
</head>


<body>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>hi.</p>            
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
      hola
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:pink;">
      adios
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Produce:

[image]

So, how can I get this?(separation between the row)

[image]

Comment: Like the style. I don't know the offset, Maybe col-sm-2??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply consider [offset](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting) like below. You have a total of 9 columns of the grid used (6 + 3) so you can add an offset up to 3 to have a total of 12.

*(i replaced `sm` with `xs` to see the result in the reduced snippet)*

```css
.row {
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>hi.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
      hola
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-3" style="background-color:pink;">
      adios
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
      hola
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-2" style="background-color:pink;">
      adios
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
      hola
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color:pink;">
      adios
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually bootstrap does have a "gutter space" between columns. What you need is an element inside your col-div-* for this gutter to be visible. You could also use an offset as others have suggested, but you have to think about what you really  want to to accomplish.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
</head>


<body>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>hi.</p>            
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9" >
      <div style="background-color:yellow; padding: 10px;">hola</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div style="background-color:pink;">adios</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Omar :) One question more: How can I put "padding" between the "hola" and the yellow block?

Comment: also, remember to use classes instead of inline styles. This could save you from a world of hurt

Answer (score 1):

I have added the code according to the latest bootstrap v4. There are slight changes in the syntax while giving offset. And also the breakpoints have changed. xs in bootstrap v3 is equal to sm in bootstrap 4, md equal to lg and likewise.Hope it will be helpful.

Refer for more : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>


<body>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>hi.</p>            
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
      hola
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 offset-sm-3" style="background-color:pink;">
      adios
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You no more need to include the link with alpha version .. the migration is done ... also correct the js of boostrap or remove it, you kept the old one